# Assuring that HTTP cannot be used with NSImage initWithContentsOfUrl (and other such APIs)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsurl

I have code to synchronously load an image from a website:

```objectivec
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithCString:urlString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
returnImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

And also this code to synchronously load a file.

```objectivec
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithCString:pURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSError * error;
NSData * dataFromFileAtURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
```

As an aside, I have just discovered that `dataFromContentsOfUrl` is not recommended for this purpose, and I guess I will be changing it to use `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest]`. But for now, this is the code, and I suspect my question applies to either version.

Both of these are correctly downloading files from the internet, and both are refusing to download insecure `http:` links. Refusing insecure links is the behavior I need, so a more trusting soul than I am might conclude I was done. But I can't find any documentation that guarantees that they will be refused. I am concerned that there may be circumstances where these APIs may accept insecure links. Is there documentation somewhere about how to control this? Google searches have not proven fruitful.

Comment: `+sendSynchronousRequest` is deprecated for the same reason that `...withContentsOfURL` methods are discouraged. You should replace these with asynchronous code. There is no recommended synchronous approach.

Comment: I wondered if that weren't the case. I have decided to punt the file download issue for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is documented in the [NSAppTransportSecurity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity) documentation and the [Preventing Insecure Network Connections](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preventing_insecure_network_connections) documentation. These documents explain where ATS is applied, what rules it enforces, and how to enable exceptions to those rules.